# Tips for making administration of Drupal site easier

Tags: drupal-6, administration

I'm creating a Drupal site for a client, and I'd like to make administrating the site as easy as possible for them.

Examples of what they'd want to do with the site is:

- Add/Edit/Remove content which will be displayed on various pages
- Manage a forum - Just the basic Drupal Forum module

  - Add / Ban Users
- Respond to comments left using the webforum

I see there is an Admin module, that looks pretty promising.  But I was wondering if anyone has any other helpful tips.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, what people have found useful is the [Administration menu](http://drupal.org/project/admin_menu) module.

Secondly, it's the *Edit* and *View* tabs on top of the content for signed in users. If you're using a custom template, you could just use the `<?php print $tabs ?>` just before you are printing the content in *page.tpl.php*.

UX is probably something that can be fine-tuned forever and surely guys will have a lot more advice coming for you here, but these 2 have been the most important lifesavers for me.